# HttpUrlConnection reading chunked response

Tags: java, android, http

I'm working on a project where i have to use *HttpUrlConnection* (Android~) for reading the input stream.

It turns out that when i'm reading the input stream the data is malformed and has a bigger size from the original content (which is sent by the server). Now, the server response header contains both **"Content-Length"** and **"Transfer-Encoding: chunked"**, which from what i know is an issue as both of them shouldn't coexist.

Aside from that the input stream received from *HttpUrlConnection* contains all body content (with chunks offset informations).

I have two questions:

- Shouldn't the *HttpUrlConnection* handle chunked data?
- How to get the data from input stream without chunked informations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpUrlConnection should be handling chunked data, you're correct. The fact that you're seeing these headers at all means they're probably being malformed somewhere, and something has already sent either a `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n`, so the HttpUrlConnection views it as part of the actual transmission.

If you WANT to be getting the raw data, use a socket and connect to the url on the correct port (probably 80, 443 for ssl)

EDIT: [java.net.URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) states under the connect() method

> Interact with the resource; query header fields and contents.

This shows that a URLConnection, prior to reading anything in from any sort of provided reader, queries the header information. Pardon me for not including this the first time.

Comment: Could you share some documentation which states that the *HttpUrlConnection* does it?

Comment: Also, by nature of having methods to view the header fields, that is indicative of it reading in the headers.